# Как организовать рабочее окружение для разработки на React Native в Windows?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

Хочу начать осваивать разработку под Android на React Native. Подскажите, как организовать и настроить рабочее окружение для разработки на React Native в Windows? Если кто-то даст ссылку на дельный гайд по настройке окружения - тоже буду признателен. Для разработки хотелось бы использовать PhpStorm/ WebStorm. В интернете много чего написано по этому поводу, но систематизированной инструкции я пока не нашел.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Открываете [Android setup документацию facebook по react native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.23/docs/android-setup.html) и проходитесь по каждому пункту. Затем

Если будете использовать WebStorm - просто создаете новый проект New project -> React Native. Готово.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]